# RabbitMQ configuration script

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I've a rabbit configuration file and it contains a `JSON`. As far as I know by using that I can configure the RabbitMQ but I couldn't figure out where I have to put that file or how to run it.

```
{
    "rabbit_version": "3.5.6",
    "users": [{
            "name": "guest",
            "password_hash": "GAd/n+dflOQhAEnqkF6y2V0TMrU=",
            "tags": "administrator"
        }
    ],
    "vhosts": [{
            "name": "/"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [{
            "user": "guest",
            "vhost": "/",
            "configure": ".*",
            "write": ".*",
            "read": ".*"
        }
    ],
    "parameters": [],
    "policies": [],
    "queues": [{
            "name": "stream.service.postpaid",
            "vhost": "/",
            "durable": true,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "arguments": {}
        }, {
            "name": "stream.smart.dl.postpaid",
            "vhost": "/",
            "durable": true,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "arguments": {}
        }, {
            "name": "stream.smart.postpaid",
            "vhost": "/",
            "durable": true,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "arguments": {
                "x-max-length": 100000,
                "x-dead-letter-exchange": "decoder.dl.sn",
                "x-message-ttl": 60000
            }
        }
    ],
    "exchanges": [{
            "name": "decoder.sn",
            "vhost": "/",
            "type": "topic",
            "durable": true,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "internal": false,
            "arguments": {}
        }, {
            "name": "decoder.dl.sn",
            "vhost": "/",
            "type": "topic",
            "durable": true,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "internal": false,
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ],
    "bindings": [{
            "source": "decoder.dl.sn",
            "vhost": "/",
            "destination": "stream.smart.dl.postpaid",
            "destination_type": "queue",
            "routing_key": "SMART.POSTPAID",
            "arguments": {}
        }, {
            "source": "decoder.sn",
            "vhost": "/",
            "destination": "stream.service.postpaid",
            "destination_type": "queue",
            "routing_key": "SERVICE.POSTPAID",
            "arguments": {}
        }, {
            "source": "decoder.sn",
            "vhost": "/",
            "destination": "stream.smart.postpaid",
            "destination_type": "queue",
            "routing_key": "SMART.POSTPAID",
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just find it out.

we can use web interface to import file or following command by using shell

rabbitmqadmin -q import rabbit.config